# Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\

Tags: php, html

I'm getting this Warning for some strange reason...
this is the complete warning:

```
Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\wamp64\www\Petrogas NCR applicatie\Insert.php on line 84
```

This is my code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attachments']['name']); $i++)
    {
        function resize_image($file,$max_resolution) {
            if (file_exists($file)) {

                $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

                $original_width = imagesx($original_image);
                $original_height = imagesy($original_image);

                $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_width;
                $new_width = $max_resolution;
                $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

                if ($new_height > $max_resolution) {
                    $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_height;
                    $new_height = $max_resolution;
                    $new_width = $original_width * $ratio;
                }

                if ($original_image) {
                    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                    imagecopyresampled($new_image,$original_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$original_width,$original_height);
                    imagejpeg($new_image,$file,90);
                }
            }
        }
        $filetmp = $_FILES["attachments"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES["attachments"]["name"][$i];
        $filepath = "images/".$filename;
        if (move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath)) {
            $file = $_FILES['attachments']['name'];
            resize_image($file, '50');
            $querypictureupload = "INSERT INTO file_upload(ncrnummer,filename) VALUES ('$ncrnummer','$filename')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $querypictureupload);
        }
    }
```

I was trying to upload an image and resize it. But got this strange warning...

Comment: Firstly, you are re-declaring your function on each iteration!

Comment: As the error suggests, you are passing an array instead of a string to `file_exists` so your next step would be to find where you are calling `file_exists` and dump whatever is being passed to it to see what is being passed to it.

Comment: Too many issues with this code.  Take a step back and start smaller in learning php

Comment: @DavidWinder that would throw an error as it is an array that is being passed. It is always better to dump.

Comment: For multiple inputs with type `file` - `$_FILES['attachments']['name']` will be __array__.

Comment: @OP To answer your question: replace `$file = $_FILES['attachments']['name'];` with `$file = $_FILES['attachments']['name'][$i];`

Comment: firstly why are you creating function inside for loop?? you can call function. you can't create it inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as you should not create function inside for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attachments']['name']); $i++)
{        
    $filetmp = $_FILES["attachments"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES["attachments"]["name"][$i];
    $filepath = "images/".$filename;
    if (move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath)) {
        $file = $_FILES['attachments']['name'];
        resize_image($file, '50', $filepath);
        $querypictureupload = "INSERT INTO file_upload(ncrnummer,filename) VALUES ('$ncrnummer','$filename')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $querypictureupload);
    }
}
```

Create function outside of the scope of for loop function

And you need to pass file path in `file_exists` function to check whether the file exists or not

```
 function resize_image($file,$max_resolution, $filepath) {
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {

            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);

            $original_width = imagesx($original_image);
            $original_height = imagesy($original_image);

            $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_width;
            $new_width = $max_resolution;
            $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;

            if ($new_height > $max_resolution) {
                $ratio = $max_resolution / $original_height;
                $new_height = $max_resolution;
                $new_width = $original_width * $ratio;
            }

            if ($original_image) {
                $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                imagecopyresampled($new_image,$original_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$original_width,$original_height);
                imagejpeg($new_image,$file,90);
            }
        }
    }
```